# Items of a ListView have DropDownList: How to get the DataItem when selection changes?

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, dataitem

So I have something like this:

[image: My ListView setup]

Under the "Products" ComboBox there is a ListView that displays the new items that are added when the user clicks the "Add" button to add the selected product.

When the user makes a Product Descriptor selection for a product, I need to change a property of the associated data bound object.  How do I access that object?  I have a handler for the SelectedIndexChanged event of a given Product Descriptor ComboBox, but how do I get the DataItem of the row containing the ComboBox that had its selection changed?

I thought about ListView's ItemCommand event, but I can't see how I would use it in this case.

I also saw this post, in which one answer mentions storing ids in hiddenfields:
[DropDownList inside Repeater: How to handle SelectedIndexChange and get DataItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509834/dropdownlist-inside-repeater-how-to-handle-selectedindexchange-and-get-dataitem)

But in that case, how would I get the Ids from those hidden fields?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just realized that the question I referenced probably has what I need in the accepted answer.  Will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Schmelter's answer led me to this answer:

```
            Dim comboBox = CType(sender, RadComboBox)
            Dim item = CType(comboBox.NamingContainer, ListViewItem)
            Dim myListItem = myCollection(item.DataItemIndex)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to cast the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of the `DropDownList`:

```
var ddl      = (DropDownList) sender;
var item     = (ListViewItem) ddl.NamingContainer;
var rowView  = (DataRowView)  item.DataItem;
```

Comment: Thanks much. This this lead me to the right answer.  DataItem is Null in my case, so I ended up using item.DataItemIndex to index into the collection I bind to