# DropDownList with DataSource and SelectedValue from Object

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I have an object Call ToOrder. In the Object I have 2 fields: 
 - int[Q] avaibleQuantity (Q gets the value from DB and populate a DDL in aspx)
 - int selectedQuantity (selectedQuantity gets the value from DDL in aspx and will be register in DB).

In my form I have a repeater that get List and populate all the field.
EX:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul class="horizontal">
                        </ul>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <img src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImagePath") %>" width="60" height="40" alt = "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %>"/>
                            <p>
                                ID:
                                <asp:Literal ID="ProductIDLiteral" runat="server" 
                                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>'></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="NameLiteral" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Literal>
                                <asp:Literal ID="ProductNameLiteral" runat="server" 
                                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %>'></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="Price ($): "></asp:Literal>
                                <asp:Literal ID="UnitPriceLiteral" runat="server" 
                                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UnitPrice") %>'></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="QuantityLiteral" runat="server" Text="Quantity: "></asp:Literal>

                                         <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLQuantity" runat="server" 
        DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "avaibleQuantity")%>' 
        ondatabinding="SelectedQuantity"></asp:DropDownList>
        </p> 
        <p>
        <asp:Literal ID="CheckLiteral" runat="server" Text="Keep this article: "></asp:Literal><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"
                                runat="server" Checked="True" />
                            </p>
                        </li>
```

Well, I have a problem with my dropdownList.
I don't know how to find the object (toOrder) which matching each DDL.

For exemple:
I have 2 object:

```
 A { avaibleQuantity  = <1,2,3,4>
    SelectedQuantity = 2
`}
    B { 
avaibleQuantity  = <1,2>
SelectedQuantity = 1
}
```

If I change the Value of the first DDL to be 1. How can I reach the object A?
Thank you

Comment: I asked: Why can't I get the value of each of my repeter's control?

Comment: Or How can I bind the selectedIndex to my model

Comment: I've found a similar request [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509834/dropdownlist-inside-repeater-how-to-handle-selectedindexchange-and-get-dataitem